# Why does SFINAE only apply to one of these two seemingly identical functions?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

The following code does not compile (With clang 7.0, --std=c++17):

```
struct Foo {
    void foo() {}
};
struct Bar {
    void bar() {}
};
struct Both {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

template <typename T, typename>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.foo();
}

template <typename T, typename...>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.bar();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DoStuff(Foo());
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>:19:11: error: no member named 'bar' in 'Foo'
    input.bar();
    ~~~~~ ^

<source>:23:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'DoStuff<Foo>' requested here
    DoStuff(Foo());
```

However, if you change `Foo()` to `Bar()` (or `Both()`) it compiles just fine. In the `Bar()` case, this shows that SFINAE is taking effect; in the `Both()` case it shows that the `typename...` overload has lower precedence, so the other one is chosen when both apply.

But what I don't understand is why SFINAE applies to the `Bar()` case but not the `Foo()` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SFINAE going on here. All calls to `DoStuff` are going to call

```
template <typename T, typename...>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.bar();
}
```

The reason for this is that

```
template <typename T, typename>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.foo();
}
```

requires two template parameters while

```
template <typename T, typename...>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.bar();
}
```

works for 1 or more template parameters (variadic packs are allowed to be empty).  So when you call

```
DoStuff(Foo());
// or
DoStuff(Bar());
//or
DoStuff(Both());
```

you can only deduce a single template parameter and the only viable candidate is

```
template <typename T, typename...>
void DoStuff(T input) {
    input.bar();
}
```

If you had used

```
DoStuff<Foo, any_other_type>(Foo());
```

then you'd get an ambiguity error since it matches both templates.